# get revert reason (handleRevert) of faild transaction using web3js

Tags: node.js, typescript, solidity, web3js

I tried so many ways (literally all of them) and still can't get revert reason on web3js. My version of web3js is 1.9.0, I have a simple solidity contract which cast votes like this:

```
 function addVote(string memory voteName, string memory candidate, address addr) public returns(string memory){

        require(candidateVote[voteName].length > 0, "Vote does not exist.");
        // require(voteCount[voteName][candidate] == 0, "You have already voted for this candidate.");
        require(!voters[voteName][addr], "Address has already voted!");

        voteCount[voteName][candidate]++;
        // voteCount[address][voteName][candidate]++

        voters[voteName][addr] = true;
        
        return "Vote successful casted!";
    }
```

as you can see, I have 3 require, and this is my web3js call in nodejs:

```
export function addVote(web3:any, contract:any, abi: any,contractAddress:any,voteName:string, candidate:any, fromAccount:any){
  
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                
                contract.methods.addVote(voteName, candidate, fromAccount).send({from:fromAccount,gas:3000000})
                
                .on('confirmation', function(confirmationNumber, receipt){
                
                        if(receipt.status){
                                resolve(receipt)
                            }else{

                               reject(receipt)
                                
                            }

                }).on('error', function(error, receipt) {
                        
                        reject(error)

                })
        })
}
```

and this the output:

```
E:\Docker-project\dvote\node_modules\web3-utils\lib\index.js:49
        error = new Error(error);
                ^
Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "transactionHash": "0xd3dc4740bb91d16b94b7214914347531e494c46582dcb69c12bc488133e49d06",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "blockNumber": 20,
  "blockHash": "0x3a50b40559ac7e6ae7dad11fe73ec36e8c9be536fa8e5e6b1353cbf7ca3a96fd",
  "from": "0x5d256d7b2238958831d55d9d6e0d08e51e3dd1d8",
  "to": "0x25fde715c938ac5a27cd06aa3887981d0457f330",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 29872,
  "gasUsed": 29872,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 2570615365,
  "type": "0x2",
  "events": {}
}
    at Object._fireError (E:\Docker-project\dvote\node_modules\web3-utils\lib\index.js:49:17)
    at E:\Docker-project\dvote\node_modules\web3-core-method\lib\index.js:396:39
```

I must mention that I used and set web3.eth.handleRevert = true, nothing happened! I also used getTransactionReceipt on trxhash, I hoped maybe that object include revert reason and it was nothing.